# Openvpn SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting error

Tags: 16.04, openvpn

I need to enter user name password and then google authentication code.

So to save user password, i changed this line

```
   auth-user-pass /home/pass.txt
static-challenge "Enter Google Authenticator Code" 1
```

but now it does not ask google autenticaion code and gives this error:

```
Thu Aug 30 18:50:09 2018 SENT CONTROL [OpenVPN Server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Thu Aug 30 18:50:09 2018 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED,CRV1:R,E:a7L06JFsVpOIQMc5XftM0kA+7trXwyG0:ZWZlY3R1cmEuY2F5ZGlu:Enter Google Authenticator Code
Thu Aug 30 18:50:09 2018 SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
```

what should i do